# Toggling a class in JS

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, event-handling

I'm toggling the class of an element with this code but I'm pretty sure it can be written more efficiently.

```
$('.expandable_header').click(function() {
    toggle_expandable_icon($(this).find('i')[0]);
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.expandable_header').slideToggle(100, function(){
    });
});

function toggle_expandable_icon(elem) {
    var toOpen = 'fa-plus-circle';
    var toClose = 'fa-minus-circle';
    if (elem.classList.contains(toOpen)) {
        elem.classList.replace(toOpen, toClose);
    } else {
        elem.classList.replace(toClose, toOpen);
}};
```

Not pointless to say js is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 3):

### Use toggle methods

Presuming that you are just toggling those two classes, you could just use [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) with those two class names:

```
function toggle_expandable_icon(elem) {
    elem.classList.toggle('fa-plus-circle');
    elem.classList.toggle('fa-minus-circle');
}
```

And it appears jQuery is used, so the [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) method could be used on a jQuery collection (i.e. remove the `[0]` in `toggle_expandable_icon($(this).find('i')[0]);`):

```
function toggle_expandable_icon(collection) {
    collection.toggleClass('fa-plus-circle').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle');
}
```

Those class names could also be added together in a single `toggleClass()` call:

```
function toggle_expandable_icon(collection) {
    collection.toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle');
}
```

### Demo

Without knowing the HTML structure it was challenging to know exactly how the toggles operated, but it wasn't very difficult to generate something.

```js
$('.expandable_header').click(function() {
    toggle_expandable_icon($(this).find('i'));
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.expandable_header').slideToggle("slow");
});

function toggle_expandable_icon(collection) {
    collection.toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <tr class="expandable_header">
    <td>
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none;" height="250px">
    <td>                                                           
                                                                                                                               <a href="https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1511/120114" target="_blank"> Zombies exist! </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent ! And neither I was aware for the zombies...